# Stopping specific jQuery animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have multiple animations on a single object, and I need to stop a specific animation rather than all of them.  It doesn't look like the .stop() method can do this.

For instance, when animating opacity and width simultaneously, I may need to cancel the opacity animation while still completing the width animation.  It would seem that this is not possible, but I am hoping that someone knows a trick or an API call that I'm missing.

**Note:** I'm not talking about queued animations, I'm looking to animate multiple attributes at the same time with the ability to stop some of those attribute animations after they have already started

Comment: I would have thought there would be a way using custom named queues, but it doesn't seem like the `.stop()` method can target a specific queue (far as I can tell anyway).

Comment: For now I've made a request for this feature to be added http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8227

Comment: What is the criteria for stopping an animation? Is it based on a user action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hate to be a guy who answers his own question (thanks so much for the detailed responses and putting brain power into it!) but I have found a direct answer.  Apparently there is a parameter for the .animate() method called "queue" which defaults to true but you can set to false in order to have your animation take place immediately.

This means that by setting queue to false you can run multiple animations using separate calls without having to wait for the previous one to finish.  Better yet, if you try to run an animation for a property which is already being animated, the second will override the first.  This means you can stop a property's animation by simply "animating" it to its current value with a duration of 0, using queue "false".

**An Example:**

```
$myElement = $("#animateElement");
$myElement.animate({width: 500}, {duration: 5000});
$myElement.animate({height: 500}, {duration: 5000, queue: false});
// ... Wait 2 seconds ...
$myElement.animate({width: $myElement.width()}, {duration: 0, queue: false});
```

[Another option](http://jsfiddle.net/jitter/Egp2G/) was suggested by a gracious jQuery contributor who responded to my enhancement request.  This takes advantage of the ability to use a step function on an animation (step functions are called at every point in the animation, and you can manipulate the animation parameters based on whatever criteria you want).  Although this also could have solved the issue, I felt it was far more dirty than the "queue: false" option.

Answer (score 3):

After thinking about this a little harder about this, I realized that what you're trying to do isn't easy doable because of the way animations are handled in jQuery.

Since animations are managed by a queue, it not possible to run concurrent animations on the same element without them being in the same function.

That is to say,

```
$(element).animate(aThing, aTime);
          .animate(anotherThing, anotherTime);
```

isn't going to run in parallel. *aThing* will finish in *aTime*, followed by *anotherThing* lasting for *anotherTime*.

Thus, you can only accomplish multiple changes by having them in the same function:

```
$(element).animate({aThing: aValue, anotherThing: anotherValue}, aTime);
```

---

Here's a quick explanation of the anatomy of how animation functions are handled within jQuery.

A timer object is assigned to the element for the duration of the animation:

```
function t( gotoEnd ) {
    return self.step(gotoEnd);
}

t.elem = this.elem;
jQuery.timers.push(t);
```

When you call the stop function, it removes the timer from timers:

```
// go in reverse order so anything added to the queue during the loop is ignored
for ( var i = timers.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if ( timers[i].elem === this ) {
        if (gotoEnd) {
            // force the next step to be the last
            timers[i](true);
        }

        timers.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

So, there is no way to remove a specific property of an animation function since the timer itself is killed.

---

The only way I could think of accomplishing this would be to keep track of the start time and duration, re-enqueuing the animation and stopping the current one.

```
var start = $.now();
var duration = 5000;

$(element).animate({opacity: '0.5', width: '500px'}, duration);
```

...

```
var remaining = duration - ($.now() - start);
$(element).animate({opacity: '0.5', remaining)
          .stop();
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response!  I may not fully understand, but it looks like this code will cause a width animation lasting 5 seconds, at which point the opacity animation will begin.  I need to be able to run both the width and opacity animations at the same time (i.e. both width and opacity are changing), with the ability to stop one or the other before completion without stopping both.

Comment: Alright, I've revised my answer now that I actually have a better understanding of your question : ).

Comment: Hi Ian -- I just wanted to thank you so much for such a detailed answer.  I was able to find a direct solution which doesn't require any sort of tracking, so unfortunately I can't give you the answer tag :(.  Hopefully you'll be able to use the solution some day though!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of one animation, can you break it up into several smaller animations (i.e. animate opacity from 0-20%, then animate from 20-40%, then 40-60%, etc) and instead of `.stop()`-ing the animation, you just dont start it up again?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2013**

As of jQuery 1.7 you can use `.animate()` with a named queue, and use `.stop(queuename)` to stop only those animations in the queue.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jQuery cycle plugin to animate a dozen slide shows on the same page using various different animation types (wipes, shuffles, zooms, etc). I then had my own tiny script to fade the images slightly as you hovered over each slideshow:

```
# This code stops all current animations on an element

$(".box img").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow",0.7);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast",1);
    }
);
```

The problem was the `.stop()` function was also stopping the cycle plugin in it tracks - my wipes, shuffles and zooms were stopping abruptly half way through their animation leaving the page fractured and out of position. The solution was to implement your queue "false" idea:

```
# This code suited me better - it leaves the other running animations untouched

$(".box img").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.7}, {duration: 1000, queue: false});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 250, queue: false});
    }
);
```