# how to stop only one property from animating

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to stop a property from animating with jquery. I tried using the stop method but that stops all animations on that element. I have a fadeIn and am also animating position on a dom element at the same time. Well I guess the timing is slightly off as I have a delay on the fadeIn. Then on a mouseMove handler I have a animate to mouse position.

I'm trying to put a stop on the animate but not effect the fadeIn. The problem is when I call the stop on the element it also cancels out the fadeIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exists direct function for manipulation with separate animations but here is post with workaround which may help you.

[Stopping specific jQuery animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949784/stopping-specific-jquery-animations)