# Using jQuery .stop() To Stop Only the .fadeTo() Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two jQuery effects going on with a `<div>` on my web page. I use `animate()` to move it right and left, and I use `fadeTo()` to fade it out when the mouse is not over the `<div>`.

I'd like to use the jQuery `stop()` function to prevent multiple fading effects if the mouse goes back and forth over the `<div>` very quickly, like so:

```
$("myDiv").stop().fadeTo(speed, opacity, callback);
```

Unfortunately, if I do this then it also stops my animation, which I never want. If I ever start the animation, I always want it to finish. **How can I accomplish this, while preventing the flickering fading problem as well?**

I noticed this in the [jQuery documentation for stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, if the first argument is provided as a string, only the animations in the queue represented by that string will be stopped.

This seems like the solution to my problems! Or at least it did until I tried to find out how to assign the `fadeTo` effect to a named queue. I can easily see how to do this with `animate()`, by using the options parameter as specified in the [animate() jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). But it does not look like there is something comparable in the [fadeTo() jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/). But it's weird because I can see the ability to specify this option in the documentation for `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`, and for `fadeToggle()`. But why not for `fadeTo()`?

Am I missing something here? Or is there some other way to accomplish what I want?

---

**Edit:** Below is a simplified version of my code, to help illustrate my problem.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3">
            <div id="div4">
            </div>
        </div>
    <button id="myButton" onclick="doACoolAnimation()" ></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this JavaScript to accomplish the fading:

```
$('#div1').mouseenter(function() {
    fadeElementTo('div1', 500, 1);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    fadeElementTo('div1', 500, 0.5);
});
```

My `fadeElementTo()` function is pretty simple:

```
function fadeElementTo(eid, speed, opacity, callback) {
    $("#" + eid).stop().fadeTo(speed, opacity, callback);
}
```

When my button is clicked, it animates the same `div` as was faded by simply moving it left or right.

```
function doACoolAnimation() {
    var hiddenState = GLOBAL_VAR.hiddenState;

    // If the <div> is already hidden, make it visible
    if (hiddenState == null || hiddenState == 1) {
        GLOBAL_VAR.hiddenState = 0;
        $("#div1").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 1500);
    }
    // Otherwise, hide it
    else {
        GLOBAL_VAR.hiddenState = 1;
        $("#div1").animate({
            left: "-800px"
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the problematic code please.

Comment: Sort of a duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949784/stopping-specific-jquery-animations

Comment: @ChrisA - Yeah, I saw that question before I posted mine. As I mentioned, though, I already know about using queues to stop animation effects. What I would like to know is how to use them to stop a fading effect. I feel that there surely must be a way, since the `stop()` function stops both animation and fading effects.

Comment: My question is not a duplicate! The [other SO question that has been referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949784/stopping-specific-jquery-animations) addresses a different problem. Please read my question carefully before voting to close it! I explicitly state that using `stop()` to stop an animation is a different problem than using `stop()` to stop a fade effect (and only the fade effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the fadeTo function on hover, you could try using an animate function with queue:false to animate the opacity.

```
function fadeElementTo(eid, speed, target-opacity) {
    $("#" + eid).animate({opacity: target-opacity}, {duration: speed, queue: false});
}
```